# How to save a hash to a Sequel DB?

Tags: ruby, database, csv, hash, sequel

In my seed directory I have two files: a `seed.rb` and a `file.csv`. I parsed and cleaned up the CSV file. Then I selected the information I wanted (lines 1, 2, 3, etc) and put that into a hash:

```
require 'csv'
data = {}
CSV.foreach("file.csv") do |line|
  data[line[1]] = {:address => line[2].to_s, :city => line[3].to_s, :state => line[4].to_s, :zipcode => line[5].to_s, :phone => line[6].to_s}
end
```

I would like to save this data (that is currently in a hash) into my Sequel database under the model I have made called `town.rb`. Within my model, all I have written is:

```
class Town < Sequel::Model
   #put conditions here
end
```

Note: within my migration that is associated with this model I have this written:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table(:towns) do
      primary_key :__id__

      String :name, :null => false
      String :address
      String :city
      String :state
      String :zipcode
      String :phone

    end
  end

  down do
    drop_table(:towns)
  end
end
```

So now back in my `seed.rb` file, I have this following my code written to try and accomplish saving the data into my seed file:

```
data do |key, record|
  c = Town.new #LINE 36
  c.name = key
  c.address = record[:address]
  c.city = record[:city]
  c.state = record[:state]
  c.zipcode = record[:zipcode]
  c.phone = record[:phone]
  c.save
end
```

However, I keep getting an error saying:

```
seed.rb:36:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Town (NameError)
    seed.rb:35:in `each'
    seed.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How can I save this hash to my DB without getting an error? Any help would amazing! Thanks!

Comment: Why is class `Town` in college.rb? Might be you have some problems with auto-loading. Rename the file to town.rb

Comment: If you're not using an auto-loader, you may need to `require` all your model files.

Comment: I tried requiring my model but it gave me errors that it could not load such files

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to name your primary key column `__id__`.  If you have control over the schema, you should try to avoid using double underscores in column names when using Sequel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Town` class simply isn't loaded at the point when `seeds.rb` is running.

If the comment from @SergioTulentsev didn't work, can you post your seeds file? Especially line `36` where the error is occurring?

I'm guessing that on line `36` you reference the `Town` class, which isn't loaded (or something along those lines), resulting in:

```
uninitialized constant Town (NameError)
```

Comment: I had a spelling error in my post. Please refer back as I added information to clarify. Sorry about that!